# Вывод второго меню на wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Как вывести два меню в wordpress? 
Я прописал следующие строчки в файле function

```
register_nav_menus( array( 
  'horizontal-menu' => __( 'горизотальное меню'), 
  'left_menu' => 'левое меню' 
));
```

В хедере прописал для horizontal-menu

```
<ul class="main-menu">
   <?php wp_nav_menu(
       array( 'theme_location' => 'horizontal-menu',
              'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) );
   ?>                   
</ul>
```

Но не знаю, как прописать в файле page вывод left_menu, т.к. вывожу контент следующим образом

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 

    <?php the_content();?>

<?php endwhile; /* rewind or continue if all posts have been fetched */ ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Так же как и в хедере выводите, только нужно изменить `theme_location`:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(
   array( 'theme_location' => 'left_menu',
          'menu_class' => 'left-menu' ) );
?>
```

Comment: не совсем так, мне нужно вывести меню как на картинке

Comment: Что именно не так, меню не выводится?

Comment: Слайдер на картинке и меню расположены в контенте, а не в хедере

Comment: Я имел в виду, что код который в ответе нужно вставить в то место, где вы хотите вывести второе меню, а не изменить его в хедере.

Comment: <?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
   <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>  
        <div class="col-sm-6">
   <?php wp_nav_menu(
    array( 'theme_location' => 'left_menu',
    'menu_class' => 'left-menu' ) );
   ?> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
         
    <?php endwhile; /* rewind or continue if all posts have been fetched */ ?>
 <?php else : ?>
 <?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>

Comment: Добавляю код и выводится только футер и хедер а контент нет

Comment: Ну ошибок в этом условии я не вижу, а контент для страницы есть (может вы пустой page создали)? Чтобы меню выводилось нужно еще в админке для необходимого меню внизу чекбокс отметить!

Comment: Igor Tkachuk дело в том , что страница не пустая и в ней есть html разметка, поэтому и не понятно почему не работает

Comment: Проблема моя решилась путём создания сайдбара